# Pronunciation of "live"

Tags: pronunciation

I would like to know, how should I pronounce "live" when I mean, for example, "live broadcasting" or "live music".

Comment: Click here: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/live_2

Answer (score 1):

Live music, as rhymes with five. Where you live, rhymes with give.